# adding a sub folder using activeworkbook.path syntax

Tags: excel, vba, save, filepath, file-location

ok so this is a short peace in a big workbook... All i am trying to do is tell it a certain place to save.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
    FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path "\OLD " & Range("D1").Value & ".XLSM"
```

This does exactly as it is supposed to however, i want to say basically 
"activeworkbook.path" plus give it one further step and designate a folder called "old" that it will go to.

in essence it would look like this

```
\documents\test\my-file.xlsm
```

to this

```
\documents\test\OLD\my-file.xlsm
```

any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in `"\OLD "`, and you are not closing off `\OLD` to be a folder.

The line should look like

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
    FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OLD\" & Range("D1").Value & ".XLSM"
```

I would also *strongly consider* qualifying your `Range("D1")` with your worksheet.

```
Dim fileNameRng as range
Set fileNameRng = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
    FileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OLD\" & fileNameRng.Value & ".XLSM"
```

Comment: One simple little back slash just made me feel like an idiot!!! Out of curiosity what is the point of qualifying the range vs just having it straight in code?

Comment: It's good practice. One day you may not be on the correct worksheet (or workbook) and the value will pull from somewhere that you didn't intend for it to.